# Override a stemmed word on the fly in a query with Spinx?

Tags: sphinx, stemming

If I turn on stemming/lemmatizer in sphinx can I push a term to it "as needed" that does not utilize stemming? I know I can use wordforms to always ignore that word from stemming e.g. Radiology > Radiology but that results in never stemming the word. I'm looking for a way to not add as a wordform exception but be able to in a query in essence say 'look exactly for "Radiology" and do not stem/lemmatize". I have tried "Radiology" instead of Radiology to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-index-exact-words
:)

Then can do

```
=Radiology
```

(in extended match mode)

Comment: That is interesting because the I get this error re index_exact_words on configuation: WARNING: index 'idx_XMLer': dict=keywords and prefixes and morphology enabled, forcing index_exact_words=1.  Not sure if this explains why though originally Radiography matched to Radiographer/ic now it does not. Is there a difference between the >= and >, the documentation says you *can* use > now but not sure if that is shorthand or has a different meaning.

Comment: So you already have index_exact_words enabled for you, and can use the exact form operator already. The question about wordforms is best addressed elsewhere.